# update country_state_select gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

i want to update country_state_select gem...

This is my Gemfile

```
gem 'country_state_select'
gem 'chosen_rails'
gem 'compass-rails'
```

And after `bundle` ,i will start my rails application `rails s`

I have error,it look ilke

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `state_options' for CountryStateSelect:Module:
  app/views/shared/users/_light_box_login.html.erb:101:in `block in _app_views_shared_users__light_box_login_html_erb___390633241__632173138'
  actionview (4.2.7.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
  actionview (4.2.7.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:202:in `with_output_buffer'
  actionview (4.2.7.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
  actionview (4.2.7.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:444:in `form_for'
  simple_form (3.3.1) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:26:in `block in simple_form_for'
  simple_form (3.3.1) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:45:in `with_simple_form_field_error_proc'
  simple_form (3.3.1) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:25:in `simple_form_for'
  app/views/shared/users/_light_box_login.html.erb:44:in `_app_views_shared_users__light_box_login_html_erb___390633241__632173138'
  actionview (4.2.7.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
```

And i find [solution](https://github.com/arvindvyas/Country-State-Select/issues/34)

i mean `gem 'country_state_select', '3.0.1'`

But when add this gem and bundle,i have another issue..

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "compass-rails":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    compass-rails (= 3.0.2)

  In Gemfile:
    compass-rails

    country_state_select (= 3.0.1) was resolved to 3.0.1, which depends on
      compass-rails (~> 2.0.4)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Anyone help me..how to update that gem version..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `bundle update`. It's in your question already.

Or if you want to update a specific gem use,

```
bundle update gem-name
```

Comment: it still country_state_select (2.0.0)

Comment: i want country_state_select (3.0.1)

Comment: Do not specify version number with your gem as country_state_select gem uses 3.0.2 as default & latest version now. Change gem 'country_state_select', '3.0.1' to gem 'country_state_select' in your Gemfile then run `bundle install`. If it still does not work, try `bundle update country_state_select`

Answer (score 0):

Delete `gemfile.lock` file and use `gem 'country_state_select'` in your gemfile and then use `bundle install` in terminal.

Comment: ok but defult version country_state_select (2.0.0).....i want country_state_select (3.0.1)